# are class level property or variables thread safe

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

I always had this specific scenario worry me for eons. Let's say my class looks like this

```
public class Person {
public Address Address{get;set;}
public string someMethod()
{}
}
```

My question is, I was told by my fellow developers that the Address propery of type Address, is not thread safe.

From a web request perspective, every request is run on a separate thread and every time
the thread processes the following line in my business object or code behind, example

```
var p = new Person();
```

it creates a new instance of Person object on heap and so the instance is accessed by the requesting thread, unless and otherwise I spawn multiple threads in my application.

If I am wrong, please explain  to me why I am wrong and why the public property (Address) is not thread safe?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the reference to your `Person` instance is shared among multiple threads then multiple threads could potentially change `Address` causing a race condition.  However unless you are holding that reference in a static field or in Session (some sort of globally accessible place) then you don't have anything to be worried about.

If you are creating references to objects in your code like you have show above (`var p = new Person();`) then you are perfectly thread safe as other threads will not be able to access the reference to these objects without resorting to nasty and malicious tricks.

Comment: "unless you are holding that reference in a static field or in Session" indeed, or you're passing the same instance of the object to worker threads.

Comment: Thank you to all of you, it really makes lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Your property is not thread safe, because you have no locking to prevent multiple writes to the property stepping on each others toes.

However, in your scenario where you are not sharing an instance of your class between multiple threads, the property doesn't need to be thread safe.

Objects that are shared between multiple threads, where each thread can change the state of the object, then all state changes need to be protected so that only one thread at a time can modify the object.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with this, however there are a few things I'd worry about...

If your Person object was to be modified or held some disposable resources, you could potentially find that one of the threads will be unable to read this variable. To prevent this, you will need to lock the object before read/writing it to ensure it won't be trampled on by other threads. The easiest way is by using the lock{} construct.

Comment: Thank you to all of you, it really makes lot of sense now.